# Difference between normal cookies and Zend_http_cookies in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter

I am learning a Zend Framework. Its going really difficult to me as compare to CodeIgniter. I have a problem of the difference between normal cookies(php) and zend_http_cookies. I am using normal cookies in my Zend application, it works but I want to understand Zend_http_cookies and its pure concept, can anyone tell me this.. 
thnx in advance.

Comment: both way of using cookie is correct in zend it gives new featured cookie results for secured connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP cookie :

A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too. With PHP, you can both create and retrieve cookie values.

In PHP you can set cookie like this :

Example :

```
setcookie("user", "username", time()+3600);
//For getting cookie write:
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
```

Zend_Http_Cookie:

Zend_Http_Cookie is a class that represents an HTTP cookie. It provides methods for parsing HTTP response strings, collecting cookies, and easily accessing their properties.

You can instantiate it using :

```
$cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('user',
                               'user demo',
                               '.example.com',
                               time() + 3600,
                               '/path');
```

A cookie object can be transferred back into a string, using the __toString() magic method. This method will produce a HTTP request "Cookie" header string, showing the cookie's name and value, and terminated by a semicolon (';'). The value will be URL encoded, as expected in a Cookie header:

Example:

```
// Will print out 'user=user+demo;' :

echo $cookie->__toString();

echo (string) $cookie;

echo $cookie;
```

For advance you should read zend documentation from framework.zend.com

Answer (score 1):

[Zend_Http_Cookie](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.cookies.html) explains everything you would want to know. But basically it is "just" a wrapper around PHP's native cookie functions. It's not some kind of new cookie if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Except that it's not. It has nothing to do with PHP's native cookie function since it is not for sending cookies to the user. It is used to represent cookies sent or received by Zend_Http_Client.

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Http_Cookie` is not related to normal cookies. It is a part of `Zend_Http_Client` and is a class that represents an HTTP cookie.

It provides methods for parsing HTTP response strings, collecting cookies, and easily accessing their properties. It also allows checking if a cookie matches against a specific scenario, IE a request URL, expiration time, secure connection, etc.

[Reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.cookies.html)